# NSDictionary get object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, key, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I got this `NSMutableDictionary` that contains a object and a key.
The key is: TemplateID and the Object is a number.
My problem is i can't get the Object out, without the key.

Can anyone help?

```
// Defining stuff...
templateData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[templateData addObjectsFromArray:[[WebXML sharedInstance] extractAddTemplate]];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:templateData, @"TemplateID", nil];

// First method...
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
id anObject = [dict objectForKey:aKey];

NSLog(@"anObject: %@", anObject);
// In NSLog it says: anObject: TemplateID = <theObject>;
// I just want anObject: <theObject>

// Second method...
for (id key in dict) {
    id anObject = [dict objectForKey:key];

    NSLog(@"anObject: %@", anObject);
    // In NSLog it says: anObject: TemplateID = <theObject>;
    // I just want anObject: <theObject>
}

// Third method...
NSArray  * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"TemplateID"];
NSMutableDictionary *anotherDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:templateData forKeys:myArray];

NSLog(@"anotherDict: %@", anotherDict);
// In NSLog it says: anotherDict: TemplateID = <theObject>;
// I just want anotherDict: <theObject>
```

// Mikkel

Comment: Can you log `templateData` and `dict`? Otherwise it's impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting confused by the default log output for a mutable array?

Comment: The dict says: dict: {
    TemplateID =     (
                {
            TemplateID = 61;
        }
    );
}

Comment: The templatedate says: templatedate (
        {
        TemplateID = 61;
    }
)